# AWS AppSync GraphQL - using union as mutation return causes error

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm creating a GraphQL schema using AWS AppSync and I want to use `Union` as mutation return. I'd like to write mutation this way:

```
mutation addUpdateTariff($tariff: TariffInput!, $seasonalTimeTariff: [SeasonalTimeTariffInput!]) {
  addUpdateTariff(tariff: $tariff, seasonalTimeTariff: $seasonalTimeTariff) {
    id
    type
    values {
      ... on SteppedTariff {
        endDate
      }
      ... on SeasonalTimeTariff {
        endDate
        peakConsumption
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Request failed with status code 400
```

The field `values` can be of the type `SteppedTariff` or `SeasonalTimeTariff`, depends the inputs of `addUpdateTariff` mutation. As far as I've searched, `Union` is only used in queries and I didn't find some documentation telling it cannot be used in a different way.

Am I missing something or I really cannot use `Union` this way?

**Schema:**

```
type Tariff {
  id: ID!
  type: TariffType!
  values: [TariffValue!]
}

type SteppedTariff {
  endDate: AWSDate
}

type SeasonalTimeTariff {
  endDate: AWSDate
  peakConsumption: Float
}

union TariffValue = SeasonalTimeTariff | SteppedTariff
```

**Testing different schemas for Tariff values:**

1. `values: [String]`

**Query:**

```
mutation addUpdateTariff($tariff: TariffInput!, $seasonalTimeTariff: [SeasonalTimeTariffInput!]) {
  addUpdateTariff(tariff: $tariff, seasonalTimeTariff: $seasonalTimeTariff) {
    id
    type
    values
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "addUpdateTariff": {
      "id": "843eadcf-48bd-4d58-93ec-8bbe96db3635",
      "type": "SeasonalTime",
      "values": [
        "{endDate=2019-02-02}"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. `values: [SeasonalTimeTariff]`

**Query:**

```
mutation addUpdateTariff($tariff: TariffInput!, $seasonalTimeTariff: [SeasonalTimeTariffInput!]) {
  addUpdateTariff(tariff: $tariff, seasonalTimeTariff: $seasonalTimeTariff) {
    id
    type
    values {
      endDate
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "addUpdateTariff": {
      "id": "7f77c5d9-2b06-4bb8-a678-10996addc4e1",
      "type": "SeasonalTime",
      "values": [
        {
          "endDate": "2019-02-02"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely use Unions on the return types for mutations.  Make sure you are including the field `__typename` on your values.  Your resolver template should return something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": "?",
  "values": [
    {
      "__typename": "StepTariff",
      "endDate": "2019-01-01"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "SeasonalTimeTariff",
      "endDate": "2019-01-01",
      "peakConsumption": 1.0
    }
  ]
}
```